# glm::ivec2 as key in unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, glm-math

lately I am more a user of the Scala Programming Language than C++, And now I am frustrated in porting a very simple line of code

```
val map = new HashMap[Vec2i,Entity]
```

it simply refuses to compile in C++ with strange template errors. The equivalent of Vec2i in C++ is glm::ivec2, it is basicly a struct with two integers and some operators for math.

this is how far i got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

struct KeyTraits {
size_t operator()(const ivec2& k) {
        return std::hash<int>()(k.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(k.y);
    }

bool operator()(const ivec2& a, const ivec2& b) {
        return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
    }
};

typedef unordered_map<ivec2,int,KeyTraits,KeyTraits> MyMap;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyMap map;

    map[ivec2(2,3)] = 7;
    map[ivec2(3,4)] = 8;

    for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

The current compile error is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.5/unordered_map:45,
             from /home/arne/codelite/LanguageTest/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In member function ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_Hash_code_type std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_hash_code(const _Key&) const [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_Hash_code_type = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:535:74:   instantiated from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Pair = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable<glm::detail::tvec2<int>, std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, KeyTraits, KeyTraits, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>, std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type = int]’
/home/arne/codelite/LanguageTest/main.cpp:24:16:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:727:25: error: passing ‘const KeyTraits’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘size_t KeyTraits::operator()(const glm::core::type::ivec2&)’ discards qualifiers
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In member function ‘bool std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_compare(const _Key&, std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_Hash_code_type, std::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, false>*) const [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_Hash_code_type = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable.h:879:2:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node* std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_find_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node*, const key_type&, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type) const [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, false>, key_type = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:540:53:   instantiated from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Pair = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable<glm::detail::tvec2<int>, std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, KeyTraits, KeyTraits, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>, std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type = int]’
/home/arne/codelite/LanguageTest/main.cpp:24:16:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:742:48: error: passing ‘const KeyTraits’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool KeyTraits::operator()(const glm::core::type::ivec2&, const glm::core::type::ivec2&)’ discards qualifiers
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In member function ‘size_t std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_bucket_index(const std::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, false>*, size_t) const [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, size_t = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable.h:1170:59:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_rehash(std::_Hashtable::size_type) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true, std::_Hashtable::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable.h:911:8:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::iterator std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_insert_bucket(const value_type&, std::_Hashtable::size_type, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Value = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, _Equal = KeyTraits, _H1 = KeyTraits, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::iterator = std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, false, false>, value_type = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, std::_Hashtable::size_type = long unsigned int, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:543:24:   instantiated from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec2<int>, _Pair = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable<glm::detail::tvec2<int>, std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec2<int>, int> >, KeyTraits, KeyTraits, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>, std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type = int]’
/home/arne/codelite/LanguageTest/main.cpp:24:16:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:737:55: error: passing ‘const KeyTraits’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘size_t KeyTraits::operator()(const glm::core::type::ivec2&)’ discards qualifiers
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify a hash class and a comparator class in your typedef.
See template params Hash and KeyEqual here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

it will look like that (consider the const qualifiers at the end of the method signatures):

```
struct KeyFuncs
{
    size_t operator()(const ivec2& k)const
    {
        return std::hash<int>()(k.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(k.y);
    }

    bool operator()(const ivec2& a, const ivec2& b)const
    {
            return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
    }
};


typedef unordered_map<ivec2,int,KeyFuncs,KeyFuncs> MyMap;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in exporting my problem to stack overflow. The program should be right now. My problem is, that those template error messages are totally useless to me, because I cant read them.

Comment: Did you solve it? Take a look at the const qualifiers (see edit).

Comment: You're welcome. On this occasion, I made an edit for more appropriate naming.

Comment: You might want to use a different operator to combine the two hashes, as in this implementation, [1, 2] will be hashed to the same value as [2, 1]. You could try using boost::hash_combine (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/hash_combine_id241013.html)

Comment: you can use some shift to avoid this std::hash<int>()(k.x) ^ (std::hash<int>()(k.y) << 1);

Answer (score 10):

hashes are built in to the glm library, however they are part of the exensions so just do this after you include glm and then you won't need to write your own hash:

```
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include "glm/gtx/hash.hpp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the linker error, it tells you what you should implement or provide in the list of template arguments:

```
std::hash<glm::detail::tvec2<int> >::operator()(glm::detail::tvec2<int>) const
```

The program doesn't know how to create a hash based on the vector object. You'd have to calculate your own hash, so the map code is able to differentiate between vectors.

Edit:
I'd tend to use pointers to vectors, as this might screw up if you add some element and change it later on (so you should add const objects).

---

Edit 2:
With the updated code/error message, it seems like you forgot to make the methods inside `KeyTaits`  const, so their `this` pointer is of type `KeyTraits*`, but the value passed is meant to be `const KeyTraits*`.

Comment: I changed my problem a little bit, because the first error messege here wasn't my real problem, it was more a mistike in porting it correctly in an external Project.

Comment: in this case Pointers are not doing the job, because I calculate a vector somewhere else and need to check weather a key for this object does exist. Doing it with pointers would always yield no value, because their addresses are different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755997/1754322) from "fire in the hole" is the best one.

However, just wanted to point out an alternative solution using `std::string_view`.

```cpp
namespace std
{
template <glm::length_t N, typename T, glm::qualifier Q>
struct hash<glm::vec<N, T, Q>>
{
    typedef hash<glm::vec<N, T, Q>> VecT;
    std::size_t operator()(const VecT& v) const {
        return std::hash(std::string_view((const char*)&v, sizeof(v)));
    }
};
}
```

Good think is that this solution can be easily adapted to any other plain data types.